# Moving image in Python

Tags: python, image

I am trying to move an image in Python. I expected the image to move in the new position and be removed from the previous position on the screen. But instead  I am getting image shown in all the previous positions  as well.

```
import pygame, sys
import random

class Package(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,picture_path, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load((picture_path))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [pos_x,pos_y]
        self.speed = 10 #random.randint(5, 20)
            # Move the sprite based on speed
    # Remove it when it passes the left edge of the screen
    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen_width = 1500
screen_height = 1000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

#package = Package(r'C:\Users\Igor\.spyder-py3\Amazon1.png', 100,100)

package_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
for n in range(3):
    package = Package(r'C:\Users\Igor\.spyder-py3\Amazon1.png', 100,300+50*(n-1))
    package_group.add(package)
for n in range(4):
    package = Package(r'C:\Users\Igor\.spyder-py3\Amazon1.png', 40,280+50*(n-1))
    package_group.add(package)
    
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()
    # Draw all our sprites
#    for entity in package_group:
#        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)
#    pygame.display.flip() 
    package_group.draw(screen)
    package_group.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(10)
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the game loop, call `fill` to clear the screen.

```
screen.fill((0,0,0))   # clear screen, add this line
package_group.draw(screen)
package_group.update()
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(10)
```